# Russian text goes beyond the fields

Tags: babel

I have some problems with russian text wrapping to a new line. 
How to set width alignment and correct text wrapping?

This is my try

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,russian]{extreport}
\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}
\usepackage{cmap} 
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath,mathtext,cite,enumerate,float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}
\usepackage{ dsfont }
\usepackage{ mathrsfs }

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.}
\makeatother

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm}
\geometry{right=1.5cm}
\geometry{top=1cm}
\geometry{bottom=2cm}
\begin{document}
 Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Некоторыйтекст Некоторыйтекст Некоторыйтекст Некоторыйтекст Некоторыйтекст Некоторыйтекст Некоторыйтекст Некоторыйтекст Некоторыйтекст Некоторыйтекст Некоторыйтекст Некоторыйтекст Некоторыйтекст Некоторыйтекст Некоторыйтекст
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx. Can you please edit your post to include a complete minimum working example (MWE)?

Comment: I've added my try

Comment: You have the language options in the wrong order, so the hyphenation rules are for English.

Comment: I am changing an order, but it's doesn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `\selectlanguage` command to switch between hyphenation rules, for example if you have entire chapters in different languages. You can also use `\foreignlanguage` to typeset single foreign words or phrases:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,russian]{extreport}
\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=1.5cm,top=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext
Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext
Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext
Sometexttext
\selectlanguage{russian}
Некоторыйтекст Некоторыйтекст Некоторыйтекст Некоторыйтекст Некоторыйтекст
Некоторыйтекст Некоторыйтекст Некоторыйтекст Некоторыйтекст Некоторыйтекст
Некоторыйтекст Некоторыйтекст Некоторыйтекст Некоторыйтекст Некоторыйтекст

\selectlanguage{english}
Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext
Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext
Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext
Sometexttext \foreignlanguage{russian}{Некоторыйтекст} Sometexttext
Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext
Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext
Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext Sometexttext
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: It's working, thank you. 
But is it possible to carry the entire word on a new line (not by syllables with a hyphen) and set width alignment for the whole text?

Comment: Actually `\selectlanguage` should be the last resort. Using the `otherlanguage*` environment is more frequently needed.